# Publisher publishing message only on state/msg change

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Is it possible to publish ros2 message only on state change ? I was wondering if there is any flag that can set while creating a publisher, so that it will automatically handle publishing only on state change. I can always save the previously published message locally and compare them before publishing but just wondering if there is a better way.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/389841/publisher-publishing-message-only-on-state/msg-change/) by [BhanuKiran.Chaluvadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28829/bhanukiran.chaluvadi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 241 on 2021-11-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, there is no built-in way to do that. You will need to compare the messages yourself.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2021-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1